# How to design an 'open' list of classes?

Tags: delphi

I have a class TTask from which I derive many other tasks:

```
TTask= class(TObject)
  TaskName: string;
  TaskDescription: string;
end;

TTask1= class(TTask)
TTask2= class(TTask)
TParser= class(TTask)
etc... 
(each class implemented in its own unit)
```

Each child task has its own name and description:

```
constructor TParser.Create;
begin
 inherited;       
 TaskName    := 'Parser';
 TaskDescript:= 'Parses a result file';
end;
```

The GUI:
At runtime I want to populate a listbox list called 'Available tasks' with the name of TTask1, TTask2, etc. I want to let user drag and drop tasks from 'Available' to 'Current tasks' listbox.

When populating the Available listbox at run time, because TTask1, TTask2 are not instantiated, probably it would be smart to use something like class var to obtain TaskName. Otherwise, if I ever change the name of the task, I will have to change the code in two places.

If possible I should be able to easily add more tasks to the 'Available' list box as I finish the code for them.

What is the neatest way of doing such a dynamic design?

What I don't like mostly is this design:

```
 var Task: TTask;
 ... 
 if lstAvailTasks.SelectedItem= 'Parser' then
  begin
   Task:= TTask1.Create;  
   Tasks.Add(Task)
  end
 else
     etc
```

Comment: Register each task class to your factory (`initialization` section of the unit is the ideal place).

Comment: Registering implies adding them to a list, dictionary etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a registry of task classes. Something along these lines:

```
type
  ETaskClassNotRecognised = class(Exception);

  TTask = class
  public
    constructor Create; virtual; abstract;
    class function TaskTypeName: string; virtual; abstract;
  end;
  TTaskClass = class of TTask;

  TTaskClassRegistry = class
  private
    FRegistry: TDictionary<string, TTaskClass>;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure RegisterTaskClass(TaskClass: TTaskClass);
    function RegisteredTaskClasses: TArray<TTaskClass>;
    function CreateTask(const Name: string): TTask;
  end;

constructor TTaskClassRegistry.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FRegistry := TDictionary<string, TTaskClass>.Create;
end;

destructor TTaskClassRegistry.Destroy;
begin
  FRegistry.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TTaskClassRegistry.RegisterTaskClass(TaskClass: TTaskClass);
begin
  FRegistry.Add(TaskClass.TaskTypeName, TaskClass);
end;

function TTaskClassRegistry.RegisteredTaskClasses: TArray<TTaskClass>;
begin
  Result := FRegistry.Values.ToArray;
end;

function TTaskClassRegistry.CreateTask(const Name: string): TTask;
var
  TaskClass: TTaskClass;
begin
  if not FRegistry.TryGetValue(Name, TaskClass) then begin
    raise ETaskClassNotRecognised.CreateFmt(
      'No task class named ''%s'' has been registered.', 
      [Name]
    );
  end;
  Result := TaskClass.Create;
end;
```

Notes:

- I added a virtual constructor to the task class. That's always needed when you use meta classes to instantiate objects.
- I added the task type name as a virtual method of the task type. That allows the type name to be centralised and mentioned only once.
- The registry is managed by an encapsulated dictionary.
- The `RegisteredTaskClasses` method allows you to obtain a list of registered classes. This would be useful when attempting to populate your UI with the names of registered classes.
- You'll want a single instance of the registry.

Comment: I've been [`close enough`](http://pastebin.com/5XMWNQAm) to the same, just, why did you choose the name `...Registry` ? [will delete this later]

Comment: @TLana What name would you have chosen?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-I expected some guidelines not code. But code is even better!! Thanks David :)

Comment: I want to store the tasks in a certain order in the list but TDictionary will randomize the list. So, I simply use an array of TTaskClass (instead of TDictionary). All good now.